# AS I login to a server get the message ": command not found..."

Tags: linux

As I login to a server I get the message:
: command not found...

Any idea what the root cause is ?

Comment: also if I ssh to it, I get the mesaage

Comment: : command not found...

Comment: Command not found, means the command you typed isn't available on this system. Please provide more information.

Comment: Please add the full error message (it will say what command is not found and what generated the error). Also check your shell's initialisation files for any mistyped command.

Comment: There's one scenario where that _is_ the full message.

Comment: Possible (MSDOS) <carriage return> line terminator in start script?

Answer (score 2):

If your just login and get this message, the root cause could be a wrong startup script.

Maybe in some start scripts like `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` a command is called. Please add the full error message.